# Shape recognizer Implementation

Tags: python, geometry, computer-vision, kivy

I have a simple paint kivy I wish to add shape recognizer to it similar as in [xournal](https://github.com/dmgerman/xournal).

> Quoting docs: 
>   "The shape recognizer is also a special operating mode
>   of the pen and highlighter tools. When it is enabled, Xournal attempts
>   to recognize geometric shapes as they are drawn, and if successful
>   will replace the drawn strokes accordingly. The shapes that can be
>   recognized are: line segments, circles, rectangles, arrows, triangles
>   and quadrilaterals. Polygonal shapes can be drawn in a single stroke
>   or in a sequence of consecutive strokes."

Code:

```
from kivy.base import EventLoop
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ToggleButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.clock import Clock
class Update_Location(Widget):
    pass

class CanvasWidget(Widget):
    line_width = 2

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if Widget.on_touch_down(self, touch):
           return

        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud['current_line'] = Line(
                points=(touch.x, touch.y),
                width=self.line_width)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if 'current_line' in touch.ud:
            touch.ud['current_line'].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def set_color(self, new_color):
        self.last_color = new_color
        self.canvas.add(Color(*new_color))

    def set_line_width(self, line_width='Normal'):
        self.line_width = {
            'Thin': 1, 'Normal': 2, 'Thick': 4
        }[line_width]

    def clear_canvas(self):
        saved = self.children[:]
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.canvas.clear()
        for widget in saved:
            self.add_widget(widget)
        self.set_color(self.last_color)
    def start_server(self):
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5000
        notification_text="Server started on host: "+host+" and port: "+str(port)
        server_start=Popup(title='Notification',content=Label(text=notification_text),size_hint=(.75,.75),auto_dismiss=True)
        server_start.open()
        Clock.schedule_interval(server_start.dismiss, 3)


class PaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        EventLoop.ensure_window()
        if EventLoop.window.__class__.__name__.endswith('Pygame'):
            try:
                from pygame import mouse

                a, b = pygame_compile_cursor()
                mouse.set_cursor((24, 24), (9, 9), a, b)
            except:
                pass
        #boxlayout
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.canvas_widget = CanvasWidget()
        self.canvas_widget.set_color(
            get_color_from_hex('#2980b9'))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.canvas_widget)
        #self.layout.add_widget(Label(text="Started Server : False , Connected to Server : False",color=(1,1,1),size_hint=(1, .1)))
        return self.layout

        #return self.canvas_widget


class RadioButton(ToggleButton):
    def _do_press(self):
        if self.state == 'normal':
            ToggleButtonBehavior._do_press(self)


def pygame_compile_cursor(black='@', white='-'):
    aa, bb = [], []
    a = b = 0
    i = 8
    for s in CURSOR:
        for c in s:
            a <<= 1
            b <<= 1
            i -= 1
            if c == black:
                a |= 1
                b |= 1
            elif c == white:
                b |= 1

            if not i:
                aa.append(a)
                bb.append(b)
                a = b = 0
                i = 8

    return tuple(aa), tuple(bb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '960')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '540')  # 16:9
    # Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
    # Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')

    from kivy.core.window import Window
    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#ffffff')

    PaintApp().run()
```

Now, I have a set of points stored in `touch.ud['current_line']`. On `on_touch_up` I should pass these points/set of coordinates which replaces them with the shape of the corresponding size. Are there any such code in available, I wasn't to find in xounral source clearly.

Comment: Checkout `kivy-examples/gestures/gesture_board.py`, this should help!